Average distance between in uniform distributed samples
I was studying the book High-Dimensional Statistics : A Non-Asymptotic Viewpoint by Wainwright and encountered a question in Chapter 1.
Suppose that $X_i$ and $X^\prime$are i.i.d. samples from Uni($[0,1]^d$), $i=1,\cdots,n$. The average distance is defined as $$\rho_\infty(n,d):=\mathbb{E}_{X^\prime,X_i}[\min_{i=1,\cdots,n}\|X^\prime-X_i\|_\infty].$$
I wonder how to get the following result: $$\log\rho_\infty(n,d)\geq \log\frac{d}{2(d+1)}-\frac{\log n}{d}.$$
I think the first step is to write this expectation as $$\int_0^1 \mathbb{P}(\min_{i=1,\cdots,n}\|X^\prime-X_i\|_\infty>t)dt.$$ But then how to characterize this probability?
